# require_once function causing a server error

Tags: php, include, webserver

I am trying to use the `require_once("");` function in php, and it is causing a server error whenever it is used. I know I am using the correct path because I have checked my file directory many times and have been following a video tutorial as well when coding this php code. Any ideas to why I am getting this server error?

```
       <?php
            require_once("../../includes/session.php");
       ?>
```

The page calling this function is in a folder that shares folders -  two sub-folders away from `session.php` if that makes sense.

This file is `index.php`, which is in `public/admin`. This page calling `require_once` is in `public/admin/index.php`, and the folder they both share is `photo_gallery`.

The error is: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

All the debugging I have done is echo a hello statement before calling require_once and after require_once and when I posted hello after nothing was outputted

This is the error I receive when checking my error log:

[08-Aug-2012 11:01:04] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home3/visittom/public_html/photo_gallery/includes/session.php on line 47

Comment: try to use a full path, and see if things work then as expected. If yes, you know your include points the wrong way. Are you maybe including more from the includes themselfs?

Comment: sidenote : why not just set the `include_path` in config file?

Comment: are you sure the error is caused by the `require_once` statement? http error 500 usually indicates an error with the web server (incorrect configuration).

Comment: try to run your page as a script from the command line (instead of running it through a web server), this way you can find out what causes the web server to return http 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require and include paths are relative to the file where they are declared, not necessarily the page that is loaded by the user. So if your index.php includes another page which contains the require_once you may run into problems.

Also, check the web server error logs which should provide more detail about that 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute paths instead of relative paths

So what you need is - `require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/includes/session.php');`

Tell me if it's good

Answer (score 0):

PHP will also throw those errors if it *cannot access* the file, whether that be the wrong path was given or if they file is plainly inaccessible due to permissions.

```
chmod 755 /path/to/file.php
```